# How do I let the user pause a python script at predefined points?

Tags: python

Say I have lots of work to do, so I want to give the user the option to pause and/or halt the work.
But I don't want to end up with an inconsistent state so I can only pause and exit at some points in the program.

How would I implement a `user_requested_pause()` method that I could use as below?

```py
for item in some_very_large_list:
  do_work()
  # can't stop here
  do_more_work()
  # now we could pause.
  if user_requested_pause():
    # ask user how to proceed, then continue or exit with consistent state
```

I thought about just using ctrl+c but the `KeyboardInterrupt` can occur at any point.

Ideally, I would check if there is input available on `stdin` but I haven't found a way to do that. `read()` just blocks if there's no input which would pause the program even if the user didn't want it to.

Edit: I solved it as follows:

```py
import signal
pause_requested = False
def handler(signum, frame):
  global pause_requested
  pause_requested = True
for item in some_very_large_list:
  do_work()
  do_more_work()
  if pause_requested:
    # ask user how to proceed, then continue or exit with consistent state
    pause_requested = False
```

Comment: Read the console for input, that will pause execution. Then ignore the input.

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` is only going to occur from user intervention so why don't you catch that error and then pose a question whether the user wants to actually stop execution altogether or just pause? The act of asking for that `input()` itself pauses the code since `input` is blocking

Comment: I already wrote why I don't want to just use read(): It would require the user to advance every single iteration. Not feasible. As for ctrl+c: What if the user presses it between `do_work()` and `do_more_work`? Then I'm in an inconsistent state!

Comment: Where did I say `read()`? Twice you've used that and not once did I. _Why_ would it require the user to advance every iteration? It's kinda pointless asking a question if you just have pre-conceived ideas about what a solution involves

Comment: The read thing was toward dcg. I *don't* want the user to have to advance every iteration.

Comment: They don't have to. As I said, why don't you catch `KeyboardInterrupt`?. The iterations continue _forever_ as far as the program is concerned _until the user does something to stop it_. It's the reverse of what you have in mind

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified that the work being done has persistent effect, i.e. it changes files that need to be left in a consistent state. If the user interrupts between do_work and do_more_work and then decides to stop the execution, the files are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use [the `signal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) for this, by making the handler set a flag to tell the program to pause and wait for input.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library. Specifically if you have an [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) function to catch the keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use multithreading to have a separate thread for doing work, and regularly checking on a state variable `requested_pause`. The main thread then runs in a loop of asking for use `input()`, and sets `requested_pause` accordingly when there is an entry.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution if you want to have execution continue without user intervention (instead of pausing by default requiring the user to re-start) requires the use of a secondary thread, coroutine, or process to accept user input and set some sort of flag telling the main processing thread to pause. This can be accomplished in quite a number of ways, but I will demonstrate using only python standard library and builtin functions. Other methods may be more flexible (like detecting a specific keypress or using a graphical interface rather than command line) but will quickly run into compatibility issues as detecting hardware input is usually done with a GUI library and is usually slightly different between systems. Some libraries like [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) are pretty good, but even this one has a caveat (requires root on linux).

example code using a thread to wait for `input()` function (user presses enter):

```
import threading, time

class user_input_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, event_obj):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.event_obj = event_obj

    def run(self):
        while True:

            self.event_obj.wait() #wait for the user to resume processing from main thread
            print('process resumed')
            input('press enter to pause\n') #use raw_input() for python 2.x
            print('process will pause')
            self.event_obj.clear() #clear the flag forcing processing to stop

def main_work(event_obj, *args):
    for x in range(10):
        if not event_obj.is_set():
            input('press enter to resume') #use raw_input() for python 2.x
            event_obj.set()
        time.sleep(2) #heavy computation that can't be interrupted
        print('done with task {}'.format(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_obj = threading.Event() #work starts paused
    user_input_thread(event_obj).start()
    main_work(event_obj)
```

Due to some of the limitations of pure python this is not a perfect solution as the thread (even though it's a daemon) will not exit at the end of the program as it is waiting on user input still. This requires you to press enter to terminate the program (although all the work will be done just fine and the interpreter will just be waiting at the end of the file). Additional user instructions via print statements and some extra control logic could make this better, but would not largely change the functionality. Another option would just be to put a `try: except:` in a loop in the main file which sets/clears a flag that a worker thread doing the main work checks every so often.